# Subjonctif dans les phrases inversées commençant par « que »

Tags: subjonctif

Bonjour,

Dans mon manuel de grammaire, il y a l'exemple suivant :

*Je suis certain que vous travaillez. —> Que vous travaill**iez**, j'en suis certain.*

Je n'en reviens toujours pas. Est-ce que ça se dit vraiment ? Doit-on utiliser le subjonctif dans des phrases inversées comme celle-ci ? Est-il possible d'y employer l'indicatif tout de même ?

Merci d'avance !

Comment: Pouvez-vous donner les références exactes de votre grammaire, et, si possible,  l'énoncé complet de la règle qui accomapgne peut-être cet exemple ?

Comment: Plutôt que "phrase inversée", je suggère plutôt de qualifier cette construction de "phrase emphatique".

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord, "phrase emphatique" convient mieux ici.

Les références : « L'expression française écrite et orale », éditions PUG. La règle était la suivante : 

« Ex : Je suis certain que vous travaillez. —> Que vous travailliez, j'en suis certain.
Cette deuxième phrase correspond souvent, dans un échange, soit à l'annonce d'une restriction soit à la confirmation d'un fait déjà énoncé. »

Voilà, c'est tout ce qu'il y est écrit.

Comment: @Greg: Je suggère que votre excellent commentaire soit converti ou répété comme réponse.

Comment: @Greg La subordination serait-elle la cause de la différence peut-être ?

Answer (score 1):

Le subjonctif est tout de même relié à la subjectivité, à une attitude conjecturale: il n'y a aucun doute lié à la phrase "Je suis certain que vous m'aimez". En revanche dans la phrase "Que vous m'aimiez, j'en suis certain", la première partie est un peu hypothétique, un peu conjecturale et le poids du "j'en suis certain" qui suit est plus un acte de foi qu'une affirmation faite sans l'ombre d'un doute.